# Why fail2ban 0.8 doesn't start properly on Debain 7 Wheezy x64?

Tags: fail2ban, debian-wheezy

Why fail2ban 0.8 doesn't start properly on Debain 7 Wheezy x64?

Hi,

I'm trying to configure fail2ban to work with APF. But first, it would be great if fail2ban can start.

```
root@akdom:/var/log# /etc/init.d/fail2ban start
[ **ok** ] Starting authentication failure monitor: fail2ban.
root@akdom:/var/log# /etc/init.d/fail2ban status
[**FAIL**] Status of authentication failure monitor:[....] fail2ban is not running ... **failed**!
root@akdom:/var/log#
```

/etc/fail2ban/jail.local (Same content in jail.conf)

```
[DEFAULT]

ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
bantime  = 600
maxretry = 3

findtime = 600

backend = auto


#
# ACTIONS
#
banaction = apf

mta = sendmail
protocol = tcp
chain = INPUT

action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(cha$

action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(c$
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", cha$

action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%($
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, $

action = %(action_)s

#JAIL
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[ssh-iptables]
enabled = true
filter = sshd
action = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]

logpath = /var/log/auth.log

maxretry = 5
```

fail2ban.conf

```
socket = /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock (This file doesn'T exist, prehaps because fail2ban is not lauched properly)
```

It's important for me to set it fast because China like my server IP (according to auth.log) :)

Looking on DuckDuckGo I found a couple of troubleshooting infos:
I tried to remove and install it again.
fail2ban-regex works perfectly and return more than 10000 results for the last 2 days.
auth.log path is valid.

Now I'm thinking about installing the prerelease 0.9 version to see if it's working.

Any idea to make it works?

Thanks

**EDIT**
With set -x in /etc/init.d/fail2ban

Command: /etc/init.d/fail2ban start

/var/log/fail2ban.log still empty.

```
root@akdom:/etc/fail2ban# /etc/init.d/fail2ban start
+ DESC=authentication failure monitor
+ NAME=fail2ban
+ DAEMON=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client
+ SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/fail2ban
+ grep+ sed -h ^[^#]*socket *= /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.local -e s/.*socket *= *//g
 -e s/ *$//g
+ tail -n 1
+ SOCKFILE=/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
+ [ -z /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/fail2ban-client ]
+ FAIL2BAN_USER=root
+ [ -r /etc/default/fail2ban ]
+ . /etc/default/fail2ban
+ FAIL2BAN_OPTS=
+ DAEMON_ARGS=
+ [ -f /etc/default/rcS ]
+ . /etc/default/rcS
+ . /lib/lsb/init-functions
+ run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d
+ [ -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks ]
+ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks
+ FANCYTTY=
+ [ -e /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh ]
+ true
+ command=start
+ [  != no ]
+ log_daemon_msg Starting authentication failure monitor fail2ban
+ [ -z Starting authentication failure monitor ]
+ log_daemon_msg_pre Starting authentication failure monitor fail2ban
+ log_use_fancy_output
+ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+ [ -t 1 ]
+ [ xxterm != x ]
+ [ xxterm != xdumb ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ [ -z ]
+ FANCYTTY=1
+ true
+ /bin/echo -n [....]
[....] + [ -z fail2ban ]
+ /bin/echo -n Starting authentication failure monitor: fail2ban
Starting authentication failure monitor: fail2ban+ log_daemon_msg_post Starting authentication failure monitor fail2ban
+ :
+ do_start start
+ do_status
+ /usr/bin/fail2ban-client ping
+ return 255
+ [ -e /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock ]
+ [ -d /var/run/fail2ban ]
+ [ root != root ]
+ start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid root --exec /usr/bin/fail2ban-client -- start
+ return 2
+ [  != no ]
+ log_end_msg_wrapper 0 2
+ [ 0 -lt 2 ]
+ value=0
+ log_end_msg 0
+ [ -z 0 ]
+ local retval
+ retval=0
+ log_end_msg_pre 0
+ log_use_fancy_output
+ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+ [ -t 1 ]
+ [ xxterm != x ]
+ [ xxterm != xdumb ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ [ -z 1 ]
+ true
+ true
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ RED=
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 2
+ GREEN=
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
+ YELLOW=
+ /usr/bin/tput op
+ NORMAL=
+ /usr/bin/tput civis
+ /usr/bin/tput sc
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 0
+ [ 0 -eq 0 ]
+ /bin/echo -ne [ ok
[ ok + /usr/bin/tput rc
+ /usr/bin/tput cnorm
+ log_use_fancy_output
+ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+ [ -t 1 ]
+ [ xxterm != x ]
+ [ xxterm != xdumb ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ [ -z 1 ]
+ true
+ true
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ RED=
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
+ YELLOW=
+ /usr/bin/tput op
+ NORMAL=
+ [ 0 -eq 0 ]
+ echo .
.
+ log_end_msg_post 0
+ :
+ return 0
+ :
root@akdom:/etc/fail2ban#
```

**EDIT**

iptables rules

```
root@akdom:~# iptables -L -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
root@akdom:~#
```

/etc/init.d/fail2ban restart

```
root@akdom:~# /etc/init.d/fail2ban restart
+ DESC=authentication failure monitor
+ NAME=fail2ban
+ DAEMON=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client
+ SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/fail2ban
+ tail -n 1
+ sed -e s/.*socket *= *//g -e s/ *$//g
+ grep -h ^[^#]*socket *= /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.local
+ SOCKFILE=/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
+ [ -z /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/fail2ban-client ]
+ FAIL2BAN_USER=root
+ [ -r /etc/default/fail2ban ]
+ . /etc/default/fail2ban
+ FAIL2BAN_OPTS=
+ DAEMON_ARGS=
+ [ -f /etc/default/rcS ]
+ . /etc/default/rcS
+ . /lib/lsb/init-functions
+ run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d
+ [ -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks ]
+ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks
+ FANCYTTY=
+ [ -e /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh ]
+ true
+ command=restart
+ log_daemon_msg Restarting authentication failure monitor fail2ban
+ [ -z Restarting authentication failure monitor ]
+ log_daemon_msg_pre Restarting authentication failure monitor fail2ban
+ log_use_fancy_output
+ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+ [ -t 1 ]
+ [ xxterm != x ]
+ [ xxterm != xdumb ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ [ -z ]
+ FANCYTTY=1
+ true
+ /bin/echo -n [....]
[....] + [ -z fail2ban ]
+ /bin/echo -n Restarting authentication failure monitor: fail2ban
Restarting authentication failure monitor: fail2ban+ log_daemon_msg_post Restarting authentication failure monitor fail2ban
+ :
+ do_stop
+ /usr/bin/fail2ban-client status
+ return 1
+ do_start
+ do_status
+ /usr/bin/fail2ban-client ping
+ return 255
+ [ -e /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock ]
+ [ -d /var/run/fail2ban ]
+ [ root != root ]
+ start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid root --exec /usr/bin/fail2ban-client -- start
+ return 2
+ log_end_msg_wrapper 2 1
+ [ 2 -lt 1 ]
+ value=1
+ log_end_msg 1
+ [ -z 1 ]
+ local retval
+ retval=1
+ log_end_msg_pre 1
+ log_use_fancy_output
+ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+ [ -t 1 ]
+ [ xxterm != x ]
+ [ xxterm != xdumb ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ [ -z 1 ]
+ true
+ true
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ RED=
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 2
+ GREEN=
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
+ YELLOW=
+ /usr/bin/tput op
+ NORMAL=
+ /usr/bin/tput civis
+ /usr/bin/tput sc
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 0
+ [ 1 -eq 0 ]
+ [ 1 -eq 255 ]
+ /bin/echo -ne [FAIL
[FAIL+ /usr/bin/tput rc
+ /usr/bin/tput cnorm
+ log_use_fancy_output
+ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+ [ -t 1 ]
+ [ xxterm != x ]
+ [ xxterm != xdumb ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
+ [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ [ -z 1 ]
+ true
+ true
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ RED=
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
+ YELLOW=
+ /usr/bin/tput op
+ NORMAL=
+ [ 1 -eq 0 ]
+ [ 1 -eq 255 ]
+ /bin/echo -e  failed!
 failed!
+ log_end_msg_post 1
+ :
+ return 1
```

- :

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: fail2ban.log is empty (but present)

Comment: You can add 'set -x' (ex. as second line) to your '/etc/init.d/fail2ban' to get more output. Inspect this output to see where fail2ban have problems.

Comment: Thanks deagh, I put it in my fail2ban.conf? If I try as a command, it's not working

Comment: As I said... "...add 'set -x' (ex. as second line) to your '/etc/init.d/fail2ban' to get more output...." not your conf and not as command.

Comment: Duh sorry my bad! The output is... big. Updating original post.

Comment: Exit code 0 indicates that every was running fine.
Can you check your iptables 'iptables -L -n --line-numbers'

Comment: Thread updated ;)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. There a some deprecated config params in new version of fail2ban.

Following steps fixed that.
First uninstall with deletion of all config files:

```
apt-get remove fail2ban --purge
```

After that do reinstall:

```
apt-get install fail2ban
```

After this steps your config is in default settings and should be edited by your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid fail2ban --exec /usr/bin/fail2ban-client -- start
```

Remove "--chuid fail2ban" if you run fail2ban as root -- the default. This should show you the errors in your configuration that are preventing the server to start.